# Why is my scroll snap not working? (total noob)

Tags: html, css, scroll-snap

I don't really know what else to type here so here is some information about the project: I have to create a web-portfolio about myself at school and i was planning to do a one-pager with scroll snapping, but somehow it doesn't work and im really close to just giving up, so i would appreciate some help :)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "headerfont";
  src: url("../fonts/alexisv3.ttf")
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

.navbarcc {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-right: 3rem;
  background-color: black;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: black;
  height: 8vh;
  font-family: headerfont;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

header:hover {
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

header:not(hover) {
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.hlogo {
  width: 4.5rem;
  height: auto;
  justify-self: flex-start;
  margin: auto 0;
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.headerli {
  margin-right: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  background-color: black;
  width: auto;
}

.vidarea1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.vidarea2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.vidarea3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.vidarea4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.navbarbtn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.navbarbtn:hover {
  color: deepskyblue;
}

.vid1 {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/derpeyyy/"><img src="pics/PortfolioLogo.png" class="hlogo"></a>
    <ul class="navbarcc">
      <li class="headerli"><a class="navbarbtn" href="#">Start</a></li>
      <li class="headerli"><a class="navbarbtn" href="#">Über Mich</a></li>
      <li class="headerli"><a class="navbarbtn" href="#">Arbeitsproben</a></li>
      <li class="headerli"><a class="navbarbtn" href="#">Kontaktformular</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <div class="scrolldiv">

    <section class="vidarea1">
      <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" width="100%" height="auto" class="vid1">
        <source src="vids/svid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
    </section>

    <section class="vidarea2">
      <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" width="100%" height="auto" class="vid1">
        <source src="vids/svid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
    </section>

    <section class="vidarea3">
      <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" width="100%" height="auto" class="vid1">
          <source src="vids/svid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
    </section>

    <section class="vidarea4">
      <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" width="100%" height="auto" class="vid1">
            <source src="vids/svid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </section>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For me it's not clear what do you wath is your goal.... Can you be more specific and add some details?

Comment: [codepen scroll-snap](https://codepen.io/alsacreations/pen/GaebzJ) may help.